# What is Kiosk Mode and how can I implement it for a Xamarin.Forms application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I have been searching to know what exactly *Kiosk Mode* means. Can someone please confirm to me that running an application in full screen whilst disabling power, volume and home buttons indeed amounts to running it in *Kiosk Mode*?

Also, is there any samples available to implement it in Xamarin.Forms?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Which platform/device are you targeting?

Comment: I am targeting for both Android and iOS @KitGrose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Kiosk mode" usually means some kind of mode where operations outside those provided by an app are disallowed. Typically it's a feature of the operating system, not your app (although depending on the platform, you may need to make certain assertions in your app).

On iOS, this mode is called [Guided Access](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202612). Your app can [request Guided Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiaccessibility.requestguidedaccesssession) provided the target device is being appropriately managed/supervised with Mobile Device Management. There's another, more locked-down mode called [Single App Mode](https://help.apple.com/configurator/mac/2.8/#/cadbf9c172) which is also managed with Apple Configurator.

On Android, this mode is called [Lock Task Mode](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode). [Here's the Xamarin documentation about it](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.StartLockTask/). The Android docs have [a good overview of how to manage all this](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/).

If you ever decide to produce a UWP version of your app too, Microsoft's equivalent is called [Assigned Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @Kit Grose. Could you please provide me if any sample with you?

Comment: A quick Google search will give you all of the information you need on how to implement it. @Kit Grose already gave you various links, I'd suggest starting with these :)